# reducer - update the complete state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I want to add a case to the reducer where i want to set the complete state , not any specific attributes.

updating specific attributes[`SET_SELECTED_PAGE,UPDATE_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED`] are working fine. But when i try `SET_INIT_DATA` i get error `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`.The payload for `SET_INIT_DATA` will have complete json.

My state will be like

```
{
  "user": "",
  "selectedPage": "home",
  "message": "Message from admin",
  ...
}
```

**Code:**

```
 const reducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SELECTED_PAGE":
          return {
             ...state,
            selectedPage: action.payload 
          };
        case "UPDATE_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED":
          return {
              ...state,
              messageDisplayed: action.payload 
            };
      case "SET_INIT_DATA":
          return {
              action.payload // getting error Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
           }; 
        default:
          throw new Error();
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should probably be:

```js
      case "SET_INIT_DATA":
          return action.payload;
```

Yours didn't work because it's a syntax error. JS object initialization requires either a key, value pair (or [object property short form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)), or the spread operator. You provided neither so it's a syntax error.

Since `action.payload` is a suitable object it qualifies fine to return from a reducer, with no need to create a wrapper object since you want the object as it is.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide explanation, why it should be like this and mine did not work

Comment: Added an explanation for you.